# SQL insert multiple rows from single field in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

First off, I'm using PSQL as my database engine. I have the following tables:

```
feed_outputs
----------------------------
id |  feed_id |  key     ...
----------------------------
6      5        'Feed 1'
7      5        'Feed 2'
8      5        'Feed 3'
9      5        'Feed 4'
10     5        'Feed 5'
11     6        'Feed 1'
```

And another table:

```
alerts
-------------------------------------------
feed_type_id | priority |   label   | feed_output_id
-------------------------------------------
     1            1       'Label1'       11
```

What I want to do is create an insert statement that selects all the feed outputs in the feed_outputs table where the `feed_id=5` and use it in an insert statement that puts the `feed_output_id` into a new row in the alerts table.

I essentially want to combine the following two queries:

```
SELECT id FROM feed_outputs where feed_id=5;
INSERT INTO alerts (feed_type_id,priority,label,feed_output_id) VALUES 
(1,1,'Label2', <each feed_output.id from statement above>);
```

I've tried doing:

```
WITH outputs AS (select * from feed_outputs where feed_id=5)
INSERT INTO alerts (feed_type_id,priority,label,feed_output_id) VALUES
(1,1,'Label2',(select outputs.id from outputs));
```

But that obviously doesn't work with the select statement embedded into the values section of the insert statement. I'll want to keep the label the same (it's just an example field) and the only thing I want to vary is the feed output id. So my final alerts table should look like this:

```
alerts
-------------------------------------------
feed_type_id | priority |   label   | feed_output_id
-------------------------------------------
     1            1       'Label1'       11
     1            1       'Label2'       6
     1            1       'Label2'       7
     1            1       'Label2'       8
     1            1       'Label2'       9
     1            1       'Label2'       10
```

Do you know of a query that can help me achieve this with the current table configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
INSERT INTO alerts (feed_type_id,priority,label,feed_output_id)
SELECT 1,1,'Label2',id
  FROM feed_outputs
 WHERE feed_id = 5;
```

Try executing the `SELECT` once without the `INSERT` just to confirm that it's doing the right thing. Then you can tweak the query if needed.

This is called an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: Please don't link to w3schools, that site is full of errors. The Postgres manual would have been the better choice: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html

Comment: Awesome! Simpler than I thought. Thanks!

Comment: @horse Yes, well, so is stackoverflow.com, but I keep coming back. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
INSERT INTO alerts (feed_type_id,priority,label,feed_output_id) 
select 1,1,'Label2', id
from feed_outputs 
where feed_id=5;
```

Comment: @jrcrawfo: actually it was two minutes earlier ;)